# Download of Clickonce Application in Chrome marked as Malicious File

Tags: google-chrome, clickonce, malware-detection

It seems that the latest update of Google Chrome 44 to 45 is blocking clickonce applications.

Our clickonce application is working fine and is in production for over weeks.
This morning we got reports that when users tried to download our application it straight end up in the Downloads tab with following message: "[...].application may harm your browsing experience, so Chrome has blocked it. Recover malicious file". After clicking that message a confirmation dialog is shown and if that gets accepted the user can download the application file.

Is anyone else having the same experience with their clickonce applications and do you have any idea how to get around with it?

Thanks for any ideas / help!

(I have sadly not enough reputation to post images, sorry for that)

Elia

Comment: Google Chromium team has released yesterday an update and the problem seems to be solved now. Hopefully they keep it fixed for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it might have just been raised in the Chromium issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532952

Quoting from there:

> My understanding is that if Google has not scanned the file because it is unreachable or isn't aware of it (no public links so it can't be crawled), Chrome will block the application."

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will keep having a look on the issue tracker and update this topic as soon as there is anything new in sight.

Comment: The issue just got assigned to a developer of the team. So I guess there will be an update coming very soon! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=532952#c8

Answer (score 0):

In latest version things are worse: There is only Suppress button next to the message "xxx may harm your browsing experience, so Chrome has blocked it" with no links for "recover". The trick is to click on Show all downloads button on far right. There you will see the link for recovering the file that Chrome unnecessarily deemed as malicious.